# How to add Custom Properties to WPF User Control

Tags: c#, wpf

I've my own User Control including a few buttons and etc.

I use this code to bring that UC to screen.

```
<AppUI:XXXX x:Name="ucStaticBtns" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="484,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="68" />
```

I've added two property like Property1 and Property2 to XXXX user control. And changed my code with

```
<AppUI:XXXX x:Name="ucStaticBtns" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="484,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="68" Property1="False" Property2="False"/>
```

When I add this 2 parameters to XAML page, system throws an exception like **"The member 'Property1' is not recognized or is not accessible"**

Here is my UC code.

```
 public partial class XXXX : UserControl
    {
        public event EventHandler CloseClicked;
        public event EventHandler MinimizeClicked;
        //public bool ShowMinimize { get; set; }
        public static DependencyProperty Property1Property;
        public static DependencyProperty Property2Property;
        public XXXX()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        static XXXX()
        {
            Property1Property = DependencyProperty.Register("Property1", typeof(bool), typeof(XXXX));
            Property2Property = DependencyProperty.Register("Property2", typeof(bool), typeof(XXXX));
        }

        public bool Property1
        {
            get { return (bool)base.GetValue(Property1Property); }
            set { base.SetValue(Property1Property, value); }
        }

        public bool Property2
        {
            get { return (bool)base.GetValue(Property2Property); }
            set { base.SetValue(Property2Property, value); }
        }
}
```

Can you help me with doing that?
Thank you so much!

Answer (score 49, accepted):

You can use this declaration for your DependencyProperties:

```
public bool Property1
{
    get { return ( bool ) GetValue( Property1Property ); }
    set { SetValue( Property1Property, value ); }
}

// Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for Property1.  
// This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
public static readonly DependencyProperty Property1Property 
    = DependencyProperty.Register( 
          "Property1", 
          typeof( bool ), 
          typeof( XXXX ), 
          new PropertyMetadata( false ) 
      );
```

This snippet can be found in Visual Studio if you type "propdp" and then <kbd>Tab</kbd><kbd>Tab</kbd>. You'll need to fill the DependencyProperty's type, the name of the DependencyProperty, the class that contains it and the default value for that DependencyProperty (in my example, I put `false` as default).

Comment: The way VS adapts the generated code fragment (by means of `propdp`) to my modifications is magic. Do you know of a “cheat sheet” showing more of this?

Comment: After spending days wrestling data context problems, I took a step back and started again using this simple example.  Pure gold.

Comment: It surprises me that XAML doesn't have a way to do this.  I would have thought <sys:Boolean x:Name="Property1" /> or some such would be a much cleaner way of developing controls.

Answer (score 2):

You may not have declared your `DependencyProperty`s correctly. You can find out full details about how to create `DependencyProperty`s in the [Dependency Properties Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752914(v=vs.110).aspx) page on MSDN, but in short, they look something like this (taken from the linked page):

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty IsSpinningProperty = 
    DependencyProperty.Register(
    "IsSpinning", typeof(Boolean),
...
    );

public bool IsSpinning
{
    get { return (bool)GetValue(IsSpinningProperty); }
    set { SetValue(IsSpinningProperty, value); }
}
```

You can find further help in the [DependencyProperty Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.dependencyproperty(v=vs.110).aspx) page on MSDN.