# How to passing value from window to usercontrol at runtime?

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight

This is my user control code behind where I should get the data:

[image: This is my user control code behind where I should get the data]

This is my main window where I included the user control and set the value to the property:

[image: This is my main window where I included the user control and set the value to the property]

This doesn't work as the value is always null. Please help to correct anything that I've done wrong. Thanks.

Comment: From next time onwards post the actual code instead of image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `UserControl` is created before the `GetMyValue` property is set. You cannot set a property of an instance before you have created it...

Wait until the `UserControl` has been loaded and you will get the value as expected:

```
public UserControl1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    Loaded += (s, e) =>
    {
        string finalValue = GetMyValue;
    };
}
```

Comment: Thanks.. This works like a charm. Although I'm curious to know whether using this way is better or the way showed by @Marsh. What are the advantages of using this or another?

Comment: There is no need for you to define the property as a dependency property just to be able to get the value of it...

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need to use a dependency property as far as I know. This will replace the GetMyValue property you have.

check out this example for custom dependency properties.

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/wpf/wpf_dependency_properties.htm

Side Note: a quick way to make one is to type "propdp" and then tab twice. Then tab your way through setting it up.

Comment: Thanks for the link and the side note is very much helpful. 

I followed the code given and it works but is the **OnSetTextChanged** is necessary? How do I edit the code without **OnSetTextChanged**.

Comment: It's not necessary unless you have a binding that will need to be updated. To not have it, just remove the ", new PropertyChangedCallback(OnSetTextChanged). Then you'll have new " new PropertyMetaData("")

Comment: When I change to `new Property MetaData("")` the result I get is always empty.

Answer (score 0):

1.Make sure you had set the Scope on 'User' rather than 'Admin', otherwise you  won't have writing access to Recourses. 
2.Make sure you have saving method after modifying data.

For writing
    using Properties.Settings;

```
Settings.Default.myProperty = myValue;
Settings.Default.Save();
```

For Reading

```
String myValue = Settings.Default["myProperty"].ToString();
```

You can also manage your properties from 
Solution Explore > Your Project > Properties > Settings.settings

Answer (score 0):

One good solution for doing this:

```
private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var control = new UserControl1();
    control.GetMyValue = "HelloWorld";
    grid1.Childern.Add(control);
}
```

There are other solutions, like [Binding DataContext](http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/data-binding/using-the-datacontext/) or making a custom [DependencyProperty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25895011/how-to-add-custom-properties-to-wpf-user-control)

Answer (score 0):

You need to create Dependency property. There's no hard to do:

First you need to register:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty GetMyValueProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("GetMyValue", typeof(string), 
            typeof(UserControl1), new UIPropertyMetadata(string.Empty));
```

Then create auto-property:

```
public string GetMyValue
        {
            get { return (string )GetValue(GetMyValueProperty ); }
            set { SetValue(GetMyValueProperty , value); }
        }
```

That's all, just copy this examples into your UserControl1 class.

Comment: `'UIPropertyMetadata(string.Empty));`

This line of code give me error and I only can use **PropertyMetadata**... The problem is whenever I use `PropertyMetadata(string.Empty);` the result that I get is always empty.